# Proving $I+J=R$ implies $(J:I)=J$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, ideals

I am trying to prove that when $I+J=R$, ${\rm Hom}_R(R/I,R/J)=(0)$.

I know that ${\rm Hom}_R(R/I,M)\simeq(0:_MI)$, which implies ${\rm Hom}_R(R/I,R/J)\simeq(J:I)/J$. I have seen the claim that $(J:I)=J$ in this case, which would make $(J:I)/J=(0)$.

Here is my attempt at proving it:

For $j\in J$, $ij\in J$ for all $i\in I$ since $J$ is an ideal, so $j\in (J:I)$ ($R$ is commutative). Then $J\subseteq (J:I)$.

Now let $r\in (J:I)$. Then $ri\in J$ for all $i\in I$. Since $I+J=R$, we have $I\cap J=IJ$. $ri\in I$ since $I$ is an ideal, so $ri\in I\cap J=IJ$. Then since $r=a+b$ for $a\in I$ and $b\in J$ we can write $ri=ai+bi\in IJ$. So for all $i\in I$, $ai$ must be a product of something in $I$ and something in $J$, but since $a,i\in I$, this is only possible if $a=0$. Then $r=0+b=b\in J$, so $r\in J$ and $(J:I)\subseteq J$.

Is this correct?

Comment: I don't see the last point. When you conclude $ai$ is the product of something in $I$ and something in $J$, then $a=0$, why is this possible only if $a=0$? What if $a\in I\cap J\neq (0)$, then $a,i\in I$ and $ai$ is the product of something in $I$ and something in $J$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just this:

Since $I+J=R$, you have $1=i+j$ for some $i\in I$ and $j\in J$.

Then when $r\in (J:I)$, $r=ri+rj\in J+J\subseteq J$. This shows $(J:I)\subseteq J$.

It's clearly always true that $J\subseteq (J:I)$, so we have equality.